# Should I directly access the FIWARE Orion context broker API in my (android) app?

Tags: android, fiware, fiware-orion

I'm currently developing an (android) app which should access and update data stored in my FIWARE instance and also respond to subscriptions.

Is there a recommended architecture on how I should access the data?
Should I directly use the Orion NGSIv2 API or should I implement a middleware layer between my app and FIWARE?

Answer (score 2):

According to [NGSIv2 API specification](https://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/):

> FIWARE-NGSI v2 is intended to manage the entire lifecycle of context information, including updates, queries, registrations, and subscriptions.

By your short description in the question, you apparently just want to manage data (access and update: `GET` and `UPDATE`). So, you will not need any midleware to this.

[Here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion#usage), you can see how to use FIWARE Orion. [This paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7e0c/72a296c693399233fb5752f08964b5950277.pdf) contains an example of architecture, collecting data at Android and sending to Orion. [Another example](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Getting-Started) of Orion usage. I think these are the first steps for you.

Comment: I found this  [architecture graphic](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.TourGuide-App#architecture) and wanted to know if this is some kind of recommended architecture. I already have a "proxy" which forwards orion subsription notifciations over websockets. So the question is if I should use that as middelware for the REST API as well

Comment: This decision is up to you. If you already have a proxy that communicates well with Orion and it is good enough for you, use it. Even more if it will avoid unnecessary time and effort implementing everything on your client. The recommendation is to use the NGSI accordingly. If the communication with Orion is ok, it means the recommendation is being followed. In the other hand, if you use a middleware, the communication latency will improve, since there is another component (middleware) processing something between source and destination (e.g., client and server)...

Comment: In this case, according to your application requirements, you decide if it worth the effort to implement code and do not use the middleware, reducing communication latency, or if you use the middleware in case this processing time is irrelevant and it attends well what your application demands.

Comment: Okay thanks for your feedback. Will consider that. Just wanted to know if there is a standard architecture. But from your comment I see it depends on the use case.